# How to model tank treads?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Now, I know the common method of using an array in conjunction with a curve modifier to get the desired result. But, I'm facing some issues.

(1) The tread segments do not go around the curve completely.

(2) The tread segments get distorted at places.

If I'm not being clear, this is my set up:

[image]

**Edit:** This is a screen shot of the problem. The blue highlight is where the  array is getting distorted. The red highlight is where the array is not following the curve.

[image]

Comment: Can you show screenshots?

Comment: @pycoder alright, it's done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Relative Offset  Z value to zero.
[image]

Comment: That was simple enough..and this is embarrassing ... thanks though .. lol

Comment: @3fingeredfrog Did you mean *Relative* instead of *Rotative*?

Comment: @Tejas No need to feel embarrassed. I think this is a good question, actually.

Comment: @Scott ooooooops , yes i did. Well spotted :) Will change it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried changing array to "fit curve" and Y relative offset of 1 and I got this:

[image]

does it "fit"?

anyway also check the .blend (and the text) of this other question 
[How do I bake an animation along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64175/how-do-i-bake-an-animation-along-a-curve)